# How to restore windows 10 cmd to default properties settings

Tags: cmd, windows-10

I was tweaking around with the windows command prompt customization settings and now i can't manage to restore it to default settings. Does anyone know how to get the default setting back? I've looked around on the web and cant seem to find a solution that works.

Comment: Console customizations are saved under registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit

Export `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` before importing. I do not remember changing the properties of CMD but I would not be surprised that I did.

This is my user `Default` ntuser.dat loaded as a hive in the registry editor. I have edited it so it can be used for the current user (I changed the temp hive name `HKEY_USERS\temp2\Console` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"ColorTable00"=dword:000c0c0c
"ColorTable01"=dword:00da3700
"ColorTable02"=dword:000ea113
"ColorTable03"=dword:00dd963a
"ColorTable04"=dword:001f0fc5
"ColorTable05"=dword:00981788
"ColorTable06"=dword:00009cc1
"ColorTable07"=dword:00cccccc
"ColorTable08"=dword:00767676
"ColorTable09"=dword:00ff783b
"ColorTable10"=dword:000cc616
"ColorTable11"=dword:00d6d661
"ColorTable12"=dword:005648e7
"ColorTable13"=dword:009e00b4
"ColorTable14"=dword:00a5f1f9
"ColorTable15"=dword:00f2f2f2
"CtrlKeyShortcutsDisabled"=dword:00000000
"CursorColor"=dword:ffffffff
"CursorSize"=dword:00000019
"DefaultBackground"=dword:ffffffff
"DefaultForeground"=dword:ffffffff
"EnableColorSelection"=dword:00000000
"ExtendedEditKey"=dword:00000001
"ExtendedEditKeyCustom"=dword:00000000
"FaceName"="__DefaultTTFont__"
"FilterOnPaste"=dword:00000001
"FontFamily"=dword:00000000
"FontSize"=dword:00100000
"FontWeight"=dword:00000000
"ForceV2"=dword:00000001
"FullScreen"=dword:00000000
"HistoryBufferSize"=dword:00000032
"HistoryNoDup"=dword:00000000
"InsertMode"=dword:00000001
"LineSelection"=dword:00000001
"LineWrap"=dword:00000001
"LoadConIme"=dword:00000001
"NumberOfHistoryBuffers"=dword:00000004
"PopupColors"=dword:000000f5
"QuickEdit"=dword:00000001
"ScreenBufferSize"=dword:23290078
"ScreenColors"=dword:00000007
"ScrollScale"=dword:00000001
"TerminalScrolling"=dword:00000000
"TrimLeadingZeros"=dword:00000000
"WindowAlpha"=dword:000000ff
"WindowSize"=dword:001e0078
"WordDelimiters"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe]
"ColorTable05"=dword:00562401
"ColorTable06"=dword:00f0edee
"FaceName"="Lucida Console"
"FontFamily"=dword:00000036
"FontWeight"=dword:00000190
"PopupColors"=dword:000000f3
"QuickEdit"=dword:00000001
"ScreenBufferSize"=dword:0bb80078
"ScreenColors"=dword:00000056
"WindowSize"=dword:00320078

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_SysWOW64_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe]
"ColorTable05"=dword:00562401
"ColorTable06"=dword:00f0edee
"FaceName"="Lucida Console"
"FontFamily"=dword:00000036
"FontWeight"=dword:00000190
"PopupColors"=dword:000000f3
"QuickEdit"=dword:00000001
"ScreenBufferSize"=dword:0bb80078
"ScreenColors"=dword:00000056
"WindowSize"=dword:00320078
```